# GroupingBy, summing, and return value

Tags: collections, java-8, java-stream

Ok, I tried to ask this question earlier and it didn't go well. Maybe this is a better explanation of what I need.

I have a Loan object with over 30 attributes. I want to group by one of the attributes (the loan number, a String), sum another attribute (the loan amount, a Double), and just return the remaining attributes. So I tried:

```
Map<String, List<Loan>> groupedLoans = loanList.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(Loan::getLoanNum, summingDouble(Loan::getAmount));
```

However that does not give me a List of Loans. I get only the 2 attributes used in the collect statement, a `Map<String, List<Double>>`, which isn't what I want (I understand it though). I've lost all the other attributes of the Loan. I want a `Map<String, List<Loan>>`.

I've gathered from the research I've done that I probably need to 'new' up another Loan object, and pass the attributes in the constructor, but like I said, I have over 30 attributes, and that would be unwieldy.

How can I achieve this elegantly?

Comment: You did not make it less confusing (at least for me). If you simply want a `Map<String, List<Loan>>`, then all you have to do is : `loans.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Loan::getLoanNum, Collectors.toList()))`

Comment: Yes, I know that works. The problem is I have to sum the loan amount also.

Comment: First, it’s not correct that this produces a `Map<String, List<Double>>`, it produces a `Map<String, Double>`, as summing up a property will produce, well, a sum, not a list of sums. If you want a `Map<String, List<Loan>>` instead, well, where’s the sum now?

Comment: Suppose you have two loans: `LoanA(value = 57, loanNum = "123", name = "one")` and `LoanB(value = 57, loanNum="123", name = "two")`. Can you show how the result is going to look like?

Comment: Yes Eugene, it would be 2 separate Loans just as you've listed them, because the loan name is different. They wouldn't groupBy. If their names were both "one", I would expect to see a new Loan(value="114", loanNum = "123", and name = "one").

Comment: Yes Hoger, you are correct. I mistyped.

Comment: didn't you just say that you want to group them by `loadNum` and now you say by `name`?

Comment: Oh, sorry about that! Thanks for your patience! That won't happen in my use case. If the loan numbers are the same, the other details will be the same as well. If the other attributes WEREN'T the same, I think I would expect the groupBy to return 2 objects... Is that right?

Comment: @user1660256 unless you tag someone with `@` there is no way we know you commented to your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take-2. Let's see if I can tackle it this time. So apparently you need a copy constructor like this first:

```
    public Loan(Loan other, double value) {
        this.someProp = other.someProp;
        .....
        this.value = value;   
    }
```

then you still need to collect to a Map with a Comparator that take into consideration the `loanNum`:

```
 loans.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                    () -> new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparing(Loan::getLoanNumber)),
                    Collectors.summingDouble(Loan::getValue)))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(e -> {
                return new Loan(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`e.getKey` is actually the Loan; while `e.getValue` is the summing of all grouped values.

Comment: Thanks so much! I think this is it, but I'm not sure what the Function.identity() is needed for?

Comment: @user1660256 that's a valid question; but there is no `groupingBy` that would omit that function; even if in this case we don't actually need it

Comment: how would the groupBy differ if I chose to group by two fields instead of one?

Comment: @user1660256 it looks to me that the comparator would require a `andThen` for the second field

Comment: You are so right!! I was thinking I'd need a second groupingBy method.